# How can you view your durability on minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can you view the durability? When I do <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> it doesn't work. I have version 1.7.2, and I'm using mods, but not any durability mods. I'm using a Lenovo laptop and an Acer laptop running Windows 8.

Comment: I've found I have to toggle it several times before the durability shows up. No idea what the trick is. (standard Windows keyboard)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to games or gaming.

Answer (score 5):

Most Lenovo laptops I've seen have certain function keys imposed on their F-keys. Mine does.

For example, is your volume, brightness, mute, etc. on the same keys labelled as F keys?

If so, try pressing <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>. (Your <kbd>FN</kbd> key is the key between <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and Start/the Windows symbol key.)

Basically, think of <kbd>FN</kbd> as a shift button for your F keys and a few others.

Comment: This is what I need to do on my laptop too.

Answer (score 4):

For people not using a laptop and just using a Windows PC, the best solution for this is to press <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This will add durability for weapons to your UI. If you are using Mac or a laptop you need to press <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

This is the best way to display durability in vanilla Minecraft.

Mods are available:

- [Zyins HUD Mod](http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/59953-zyins-hud)
- [My Favourite, Armor Status HUD Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1282347-1-7-10-bspkrs-mods-armorstatushud-directionhud) requires bspkrsCore but is compatible with 1.7.10

Comment: He already knows the shortcut, he says it in his question.

Comment: I know that i was trying to make the solution clear for everyone viewing this question, also the answer given by neeoo isnt very clear and you need to press FN+F3+H.

Comment: "Mods are available" - Could you provide some links to some of the mods you're thinking of?

Comment: will edit my post in a minute with some links to mods i use