# How many blocks can can a diamond pickaxe stand before breaking?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend and I are arguing about how many blocks a diamond pickaxe will be able to break without it breaking itself. Do you know how much?

Comment: "hits" as in how many blocks can it destroy before breaking?

Comment: If you are on the PC version, you can execute a keystroke that will enable you to see the durability of any tool. [See this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/172014/29116)

Answer (score 14):

Unenchanted Diamond Pickaxe has [durability of 1562](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe#Usage).

Here's the durability of various pickaxes visualized:
[image: Durability visualized]

Comment: I believe that the gold pickaxe is capable of mining more than 33 cobblestones. Let me test though. Edit: Nope, it can only mine 33 cobblestones.

Comment: Let's add each level of Unbreaking adds a chance the breaking the block won't consume durability so unb 1 means 50% chance, unb. 2 33.3%, unb 3 25% chance the durability will be consumed, essentially doubling, tripling or quadrupling the durability (albeit with a randomness-based imprecision) - Unbreaking 3 diamond pickaxe can on average break 6248 blocks.

Answer (score 2):

1562 for diamond,for the new netherite pickaxe, 2031

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arqade! Think you could provide a source for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Diamond Pickaxe has a durability of 1561. 
You can click F3+H to see the durability of all tools.

[image: durability]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the durability of a tool by simply pressing Fn-F3-H and hovering your cursor over the item in your inventory. THe number represented there will tell you how many blocks you can break with that tool.

Specifically, a diamond pickaxe can break one-thousand five-hundred sixty-two (1562) blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the material. If it is used for wood, that is a different story.

But, it is 1562 on stone.