# How much obsidian can a diamond pickaxe with efficiency 1 mine before breaking?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How many blocks of obsidian can I mine with a diamond pick with efficiency 1 before it breaks? (starting with full durability)

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254601/87579).

Comment: Did you confuse efficiency (performance) with speed?

Answer (score 4):

Efficiency doesn't impact the durability of items.  Thus, a diamond pickaxe with this enchantment has the same amount of uses still - [1561 blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe#Mining).

Answer (score 3):

[Pickaxes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe#Mining) have different amounts of uses based on the type:

Wooden: 59
Stone: 131
Iron: 250
Golden: 32
**Diamond**: 1561
Netherite: 2031

[Durability](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Durability#Tool_durability):

> For block-breaking tools, a use is counted only if a player completely breaks apart one block or hits a mob.

For Pickaxes:

- Breaking a block that breaks instantly counts as 0 uses.
- Breaking other blocks **counts as 1 use**.

Using a tool properly maximizes its durability. Assuming a player uses a tool appropriately, the maximum durability for a Diamond tool is **1561 uses**.

So you will be able to mine 1561 blocks of Obsidian.