# Durability not showing on F3+H

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't see the durability on my Minecraft tools. Neither <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> works. I'm playing Minecraft 1.10.2 on a Mac. Please help!

Comment: What key combo do you normally press to bring up the F3 screen? Do any of the other F3 bindings (e.g: `F3` + `Q` to bring up a list) work?

Comment: I don't understand really, i only use F3 to see the coordinates...

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/172009/104387)

Answer (score 5):

Try pressing the <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> when you **aren't** looking in your inventory. If it works, the game should tell you in the chat that it's enabled.
Then, when you open your inventory and look at a tool, it should show the durability with it.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted correct answer :)

Comment: Additionally, durability doesn't show for completely undamaged tools. You must use up at least one durability point.